Create a custom distribution from values and option read from a table
I have a population of agents MyAgent read from a table which assign to each agent the parameter "Region".
Each MyAgent has a source that generate a pz agent, which is included in a population.
Each pz inherit from "MyAgent" the variable Region.

Now I need to assign to each pz a town.

I have a table with in the first column the region ( the same used for **MyAgent **and pz), towns and the probability associated to each town of the region (the probability summed of the towns in a region is 100%). Each region has a different set of town.
I want to associate the towns to the pz with a custom distribution reading both the towns and the probability from the table (considering the row with the same region of the pz).
I usually create an OptionList and then I read the value from a database, but in this case the options are different in every region and the combination of town and district is huge to handle.
Can I read the Option directly from the table and convert them in to OptionList?

You hit the "simple provided objects is not enough, I need coding" threshold, congratulations :)
You should simply use code to read what you need and compute based on probabilities. If you struggle with the code, start with simple examples from the help. See https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#writing-database-queries
